# SQL count data from beginning of the date till current month/year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

I have the data of customers from March 2019 till February 2020. I am counting the total email which was used to purchase our ticket followed by each month and the query I used is

```
  SELECT sub.monthNameYear,sub.monthName,count(*) from
 (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%Y-%m') as monthNameYear,DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%M %Y') as monthName,
         email,
         COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
  FROM `tablename`
  GROUP BY email, DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%Y-%m') 
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
  ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%Y-%m') ) as sub
GROUP BY sub.monthNameYear;
```

The result that I want is attached below. Where it always selects the beginning of the date and then selects each month then only counts the total email.

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do a window sum. Starting from your existing query:

```
SELECT 
    monthNameYear,
    monthName,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(ORDER BY monthNameYear) totalPurchase
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%Y-%m') monthNameYear,
        DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%M %Y') monthName,
        email
    FROM `tablename`
    GROUP BY monthNameYear, monthName, email 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) as sub
GROUP BY monthNameYear, monthName
ORDER BY monthNameYear;
```

Notes:

- always enumerate all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause
- the `order by` clause should be placed in the outer query
- you are `select`ing `COUNT(*) in the subquery, but it is not used in the outer query - I removed that column from the`select` clause

Comment: i was trying to count following the group by elements. But the way we have count gave me the actual booking data as well. It looks more clear with date too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT ed.monthNameYear, ed.monthName,        
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY ed.monthNameYear)
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%Y-%m') as monthNameYear,
             DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%M %Y') as monthName, 
             email,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM `tablename`
      GROUP BY email, DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%Y-%m'),
            DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%M %Y')
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
     ) ed
GROUP BY ed.monthNameYear, ed.monthName;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff the way you have generated a new column as for the counting also makes sense. But I was looking for an increment column only which I can call using php. Your help means a lot.